# Как передать JSON Ajax-ом?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Нужно передать *JSON* вида:

```
var JSON = {
    param1: 123,
    param2: "test2",
    param3: [1, 2, 3],
    param4: {
        param1: "test1",
        param2: [2, 3, 4,3, 2]
    },
    param5: [
        {
            param1: 1,
            param2: 2,
            param3: 3
        },

        {
            param1: 1,
            param2: 2,
            param3: 3
        },

        {
            param1: 1,
            param2: 2,
            param3: 3
        },
    ]
}
```

Посредством чистого *JS*.

Очень интересно как это реализовано в *jQuery* - там достаточно передать переменную c JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: JSON,
    ...
});
```

А на сервере, к примеру, `$_POST['param5']` будет уже с `Array`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: [преобразование данных в строку вызвается здесь](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L552), а здесь обрабатывается объект data
[jQuery.param](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L56)

Comment: То есть, они как бы обрабатывают и вкладывают их друг в друга ?